# Asp.net c# 301 redirect when page has expired

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, webforms, web-config

I have an expiry date in my database and I would like to redirect a web page when the expiry date for that page has been reached.

How would I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Using an `if` statement? What did you try? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Im thinking about how would I do it. I would need the server to run a bit of code every night or build something in to the admin system that checks for expired pages, if it finds one I want it to redirect the page to the home page. But I have no idea where to start. It's all database driven so the actual pages don't exist. like wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using a cache for your pages. I'm obviously not familiar how you store the expire dates, but I'll presume you have [exp_date: url].

So:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Dictionary<Datetime, string> pages = Read_from_database();
Context.Cache.Insert("ExpireCache", pages, new CacheDependency(m_strPath),
    System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
    CacheItemPriority.Default);
}
```

And in

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath == "page_expired.aspx")
    {
        return;
    }
    var cache = HttpContext.Current.Cache["ExpireCache"];
    if (cache.ContainsKey(HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl) &&
        cache[HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath] < DateTime.Now)
    {
        HttpContext.Response.Current.Redirect("page_expired.aspx");
    }
}
```

You can additionally add a SqlDbDependency to the Cache, so that it get updated when you modify the expire dates in the Database...

Answer (score 0):

You could put a `Trigger` on you database.
That fires off after a certain time or action and then test the date to make sure it's not expired.

If it is a simple code block like this could do the job.

```
          if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains(
          "http://mySite.com"))
          {
             HttpContext.Current.Response.Status =   "301 Moved Permanently";
             HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Location",
             Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Replace(
                    "http://mySite.com",
                    "http://www.myNewSite.com"));
          }
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to permanently redirect. @phadaphunk solution redirect Uppercase letters to small letters.

```
string authority = Request.Url.Authority;
    if (authority.IndexOf("www.") != 0)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 301;
        Response.RedirectPermanent("http://www." + authority + Request.Url.AbsolutePath, true);

    }
```

Note that Response.RediectPermanent method is only available for .Net 4.0 I think, otherwise you should use Redirect()